# Gradle sync error after updating - configuration with name 'compile' not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am making some updates to an legacy project and after updating grade versions I can't sync anymore.

The error:

> Build file '/home/user/android/projects/proj/app/build.gradle' line: 55
> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services'.
> Configuration with name 'compile' not found.
> Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Exception is:
> org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

The offending code is in my app `build.gradle` file as the last line in the file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried adding it to the top of the file just below this line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

I also tried moving it to the project level `build.gradle` file.

I can only get gradle to sync if I comment the line out, but taking over this legacy app I can only assume that will have downstream affects I can't risk.

Comment: Check Your dependencies. If there any dependencies with compile change it to implementation

Comment: @SahilGoyal thanks for the pointer - I had already updated dependencies to use implementation before running into this error.  Any other ideas?